# async and await in array of many objects ie more than 1000

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I Have more than 1000 array of objects of these properties like:

const empArr = [{
empName: 'sds',
empId: 'e3',
dob: '22-12-2',
.. so on 
}];

I have tried the problem statement using promise.all(promises) but i want to do it more efficiently .So, I need some help

```
function makeDBInsert(empArr) {
const dbArr = [];
const promises = [];
const LEN = empArr.length;

/** this function returns promise containing emp age **/
function getEmpAge(empId) {
return db.execute('select age from emp where "empId" = ?', [empId]);
} 

for (let i = 0; i < LEN; i += 1) {
const obj = {
name: empArr[i].empName, 
empId: empArr[i].empId
}
promises.push(getEmpAge(obj.empId);
dbArr.push(obj);
}

return Promise.all(promises).then((empDetail) => {
const dbObj = empDetail.map((emp, i) => {
return {
dbArr[i].age: emp.age
}
});
return db.insert('insert into emp ("name", "id", "age") values ('?', '?', '?');', Object.values(obj));
}).catch(err => console.error(err));
}
```

So, here empArr has more than 1000 objects in the array. Here, I am fetching emp age from db that returns me promise containing emp id. I am using promise.all to do this work, instead is there any better way doing without using promise.all and then iterating ? Thanks in Advance.

Note: Please ignore syntactical errors in the code. My aim here is just to describe my problem statement.

Comment: I don't know Cassandra well, but couldn't you just simply query the DB like `select age from emp where empId IN (1,2,3,4.....1000)`? This way you make only one query instead of 1000 of them

Comment: Question is not about db operations in cassandra  because node is efficient in i/o operations but not cpu intensive perations ike looping, it is about preventing the promise.all thing

Comment: Of course, but if you made `select ... in()` then you wouldn't have to iterate over `empArr` to create 1000 promises. You would have only one promise which when fulfilled, will return all desired rows from db

Comment: "...about preventing the promise.all thing" - but why?

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek we can use select ... in() but again i have to loop over the response and attach properties  to obj and insert into the db instead i m looking for solution using async await inside loops.

Comment: Sebastian is right, the bottleneck here are those thousands of queries, thats what you should optimize.

Comment: Async/await is not going to optimize anything here... rather the opposite. Async/await is a simple syntactic sugar which is using promises under the hood anyway so you are not going to get rid of them at all. What you want to optimize here are the queries themselves. If you want to add/remove/edit some keys in the db then try to use as few of them as possible. As I said, you don't have to make 1000 queries to get the data to modify. Maybe you could also make only one query to modify your data? What *exactly* do you want to achieve?

Comment: Maybe `GraphQL` is interesting for you. GraphQL allows you to modify data from a database query before sending it back to the client. Otherwise, just use a `for` loop to loop over your response. There's nothing wrong with that and it's certainly not slower than using 1000s of promises.

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek "Maybe you could also make only one query to modify your data?" In Cassandra, using `IN` on a partition key puts the bulk of the workload on the coordinator node.  That's fine for 4 or 5 items (although it won't perform well), but certainly not 1000.  If the table isn't designed to support returning 1000 rows in a single query, then the best option is to make 1000 individual queries.

Comment: @Aaron thanks, didn't know that. As I said earlier, I don't know Cassandra well. Still, the OP's solution with async/await is a terrible idea and he should avoid it

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution ie one loop do everything like using IIFE, async await, no promise.all and iterating on the promises response.

```
async function makeDBInsert(empArr) {
const modifiedArr = [];

function getEmpAge(empId) {
return db.execute('select age from emp where "empId" = ?', [empId]);
} 


await (function doDBCalls() {
empArr.forEach(async (item, i) => {
 /* getEmpAge(param) is DB call */
    const res = await getEmpAge(item.empId);
    modifiedArr.push({modified: res.age });
    // modify the object here and batch insert 
});
})();
}
```

Comment: Ouch! You did a *terrible* thing here. You are iterating 1000 times and in each iteration, you are creating a promise *and you are waiting for it to fulfill* and then start another iteration. This is *much worse* than `Promise.all` solution since you did not get rid of the Promises at all (as I suggested in the comments) and (what's the biggest bottleneck here) you are slowing down the execution of your code catastrophically. This way you do not make use of asynchronous code execution - you are forcing the code here to execute *like it was* synchronic which slows down your app tremendously!

Comment: Yes, I am forcing it to behave synchronously because I don't want to loop over multiple times , making CPU intensive. And coming to DB calls [await getEmpAge(param) ] Nodejs ( which is very good for IO operations)  and Cassandra plays very well .Cassandra  on a single node cluster can handle atleast 50k transactions per second. It's synchronic but not slowing down .

Comment: My point here is that the `await` in the `forEach` is causing the code to freeze until the Promise from `getEmpAge` fulfills then it unfreezes and continues the iteration. So on each iteration you are forcing your code to wait for the query to finish and then continue with the rest of the code in the current iteration and then start another one. If you used `Promise.all` you'd create 1000promises (which you create anyway here) which fulfill asynchronously and the time you'd have to wait for them would be equal only to the time needed for the longest execution. Now it's equal to the sum of them

Comment: Please see the example benchmark I've just created: http://jsben.ch/uyfPG. It shows how `async/await` slows down the code in such case. Although there are two iterations over `empArr` the code still executes way faster because array methods in JavaScript are blazing fast.